# ServiceStack with Razor - Model is null (deployed to Azure)

Tags: azure, servicestack-razor

When using ServiceStack / Razor, I'm having issues rendering a view in Azure only.

http://nehcr-dev.azurewebsites.net/with-view

Here is a screenshot of the page locally:

!https://www.dropbox.com/s/up5bmixdjmcc9bi/with-view.png?dl=0

Here is my service response:

```
return new HttpResult(new IndexResponse("Home | Northeast Healthcare Recruitment")
{
    TotalJobs = metadata.TotalJobs,
    GroupedJobTypeCounts = groupedJobTypeCounts,
    MostRecentJobs = new List<JobListingSummary>()
})
{
    View = "Index"
};
```

where IndexResponse is

```
public class IndexResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public IndexResponse(string title) : base(title) { }
    public int TotalJobs { get; set; }
    public List<List<JobTypeCount>> GroupedJobTypeCounts { get; set; }
    public List<JobListingSummary> MostRecentJobs { get; set; }
}
```

and BaseResponse is

```
public abstract class BaseResponse
{
    public BaseResponse(string title)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
        {
            Title = "Northeast Healthcare Recruitment";
        }

        Title = title;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

the beginning of my view looks like:

```
@inherits ViewPage<NEHCR.ServiceModel.IndexResponse>

@section head{

}

<section id="content" class="nehcr-content">
    <!-- JOB SEARCH START -->
    <section class="nehcr-search-hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <div class="nehcr-search-text">
                    <h1 class="nehcr-search-text-header">Search from @Model.TotalJobs job offers</h1>
                    <p class="nehcr-search-text-p">Your career starts here.</p>
                </div>
                <form method="GET" action="/jobs" class="nehcr-search-wrap nehcr-row">
```

and my web.config is:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false"/>
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<appSettings>
  <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ConnectionString" value="" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<!--
  For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

  The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
    <system.Web>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    </system.Web>
-->
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2">
    <buildProviders>
      <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor"/>
    </buildProviders>
  </compilation>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <customErrors mode="Off">
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false"/>
  <handlers>
    <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System"/>
      <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
      <add namespace="ServiceStack"/>
      <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html"/>
      <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor"/>
      <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text"/>
      <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite"/>
      <add namespace="NEHCR"/>
      <add namespace="NEHCR.ServiceModel"/>
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Locally it runs fine, IISExpress on Win10. Deployed to Azure I get this:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
HResult=0x80004003
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=nmhpfpfd
StackTrace:
 at ASP.Views.Home.__Index.Execute() in d:\home\site\wwwroot\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:line 15
 at ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage`1.WriteTo(StreamWriter writer)
 at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ExecuteRazorPageWithLayout(RazorPage razorPage, IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, Object model, IRazorView pageInstance, Func`1 layout)
 at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ExecuteRazorPage(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, Object model, RazorPage razorPage)
 at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ProcessRequest(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, Object dto)
 at ServiceStack.Formats.HtmlFormat.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<SerializeToStream>b__0(IViewEngine x)
 at ServiceStack.Formats.HtmlFormat.SerializeToStream(IRequest req, Object response, IResponse res)


ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPageBase<TModel>.Model.get returned null.
```

If I change my service reponse to:

```
return new IndexResponse("Home | Northeast Healthcare Recruitment")
{
    TotalJobs = metadata.TotalJobs,
    GroupedJobTypeCounts = groupedJobTypeCounts,
    MostRecentJobs = new List<JobListingSummary>()
};
```

it works fine: http://nehcr-dev.azurewebsites.net/

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I can not understand why you would put `new` in the parameters for `IndexResponse` , that makes no sense at all to me

Comment: The HttpResult takes an object as a param? You mean instead of newing it up before hand? Or just saying return new IndexResponse?

Comment: When you say it works fine do you mean the `Index.cshtml` page gets rendered? because from your website I just see the [auto-generated HTML page](http://docs.servicestack.net/html5reportformat) which suggests the Response DTO didn't match any pages. Also you need to make sure each of your pages are uniquely named in your entire `/Views/` folder, e.g. there's only 1 `Index.cshtml` page which would get resolved with either the `Index` Request DTO or `View="Index"`.

Comment: @mythz yes, the page gets rendered locally. I have only 1 Index page. Will edit the post with screenshot.

Comment: Ok so it looks like it can find the right page, sucks it only happens remotely tho. Can you try adding `[DefaultView("Index")]` on your method **instead of** returning your `IndexResponse` in a `HttpResult` to see if that helps? Otherwise it's likely a `NullReferenceException` occuring in your page that's impossible to determine from here so I'd recommend just removing parts of your page until the NRE goes away. Also note that all DTOs should have a **parameterless constructor** so they can be deserialized.

Comment: Thanks @mythz! I'll keep pecking away at it.